# using css set hover in ul list

Tags: html, css

this is my html file:-

```
<div id="load">
<ul>
    <li>Activities
    <ul>
        <li>Physical1
        <ul>
            <li>Cricket
            <ul>
                <li>One Day</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test1
    <ul>
        <li>Test At Abc</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        <li>Test2
    <ul>
        <li>Test At Xyz</li>
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i want to set in to css hover.
i dont konw about css hover much so give me suggestion for this. 
this is my output i needed.
hover in `Acvivities` display

```
Physical1 
Test1
Test2
```

hover in `Physcial1` display `Cricket`... 
thanks...

Comment: so basically, you want to make a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 6):

```
ul > li > ul {
    display: none;  // hide all submenus
}

li:hover > ul {
    display: block; // show sub menu when parent li is hovered
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bwTEx/)

Comment: i have add before every ul one div so what i need to change `div li:hover> ul:....`

Comment: Well that wouldn't be valid markup, but if you added a div as a parent to each `ul`, your new code would need to be: `ul > li > div > ul {
    display: none;  
}

li:hover > div > ul {display: block;}`

Answer (score 3):

```
ul li ul
{
    display:none;
}

ul > li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AyLYe/

Answer (score 2):

I won't provide the whole code, but with this base you can adapt the code to display the rest of what you need.

Before we start, see this tutorial I found with a google search: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu  I scanned it at a glance and it looks pretty good, it will at least guide you through the concepts and the process.

Here's a JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Kq7vD/

Heres the CSS that makes it work:

```
#load ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

#load ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Note that by removing #load you can cause this to work across every list in your menu.  The downside to this is that the css rules then apply to every list on your site, even if it shouldn't be a menu.  It is recommended that you keep your rules relatively specific for this reason.

EDIT to address your comment:

If your HTML structure includes a DIV before each UL, even the nested UL's then your css rules will need to adapt to that new structure.  In particular, it's also important to note that you will not set the UL to `display: none/block;` anymore but the DIVs.

Assuming a structure like:

```
<div id="load">
   <div>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <div>
               <ul>
                  <li></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Your code would then look like...

```
#load div ul li div {
    display: none;
}

#load div ul li:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i am try to before every ul one div tag so what change i need i change something like this `#load div ul li:hover ul{...`

Comment: now i want to set this all in to diff div like Activities in one div and there sub child display in other div....

Comment: set left side border in ul

Comment: It's important to note that adding a DIV in these places is note valid HTML markup.  What purpose do they serve?  Probably there is a better way for you to do it.